# Debian 7 - Port 25 opened by default

Tags: smtp, debian

I just install the Debian 7 distro.
Can u tell me why the port 25 is opened by default ? Can I shut it down without troubles ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't postfix installed by default ? If so, it may be the reason why the port is opened.